# ggcorr for multiple correlations: Warning messages:Removed 8 rows containing missing values (geom_tile)

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

I am very new to R, so this might be very simple to solve.

I have a data frame composed by several columns representing different variables. I would like to do a multiple correlation, pairing all the variables.

This is my data frame:

```
df <-  structure(list(ATA = c(26.41, 35.89, 42.68, 41.92, 37.43, 32.72, 
31.97, 18.59, 38.71, 38.74, 28.61, 21.31, 38.66, 42.82, 46.17, 
28.39, 28.17, 39.24, 42.44, 31.56, 41.95, 37.52, 32.15, 51.96, 
33.37, 32.8, 31.92, 40.21, 41.71, 32.61, 35.97, 42.44, 37.36, 
35.35, 37.08, 41.42, 43.71, 47.29, 31.22, 19.72, 23.74, 38.2, 
47.27, 47.47, 40.17, 37, 37.6, 37.5, 34.78, 35.43, 39.32, 42.63, 
42.52, 36.37, 36.71, 34.48, 40.06, 47.65, 37.1, 18.52, 36.98, 
14.44, 44.46, 26.61, 32.13, 33.11, 33.64, 37.67, 28.07, 15.09, 
42.08, 32.47, 38.6, 23.01, 31.02, 27.86, 31.19, 39.48, 39.79, 
31.22, 32.6, 40.19, 26.81, 35.29, 32.09, 28.72, 29.98, 30.46, 
29.21, 29.34, 35.94, 41.07, 29.53, 41.62, 15.12, 34.79, 19.35, 
32.93, 32.13, 25.6, 32.57, 35.48, 33.38, 24.58, 46.79, 31.48, 
32.83, 25.45, 18.45, 36.61, 23.52, 36.84, 30.09, 30.26, 34.28, 
37.17, 34.94, 20.66, 28.35, 25.22, 36.58, 33.19, 42.34, 34.19, 
50.82, 31.01, 42.44, 18.4, 36.38, 34.8, 42.34, 42.42, 20.85, 
43.25, 18.55, 44.78, 27.61, 37.62, 19.12, 43.5, 36.18, 40.5, 
28.31, 44.67, 42.46, 34.72, 19.09, 23.62, 39.61, 37.61, 31.45, 
34, 24.96, 42.34, 28.14, 37.94, 37.12, 39.27, 38.09, 49.29, 29.82, 
30.74, 38.69, 40.52, 42.9, 44.79, 35.95, 38.26, 27.76, 35.3, 
52.03, 33.72, 32.28, 39.32, 39.08, 37.47, 18.06, 22.61, 40.1, 
32.5, 22.51, 39.48, 37.27, 33.2, 27.54, 23.09, 23.94, 34.22, 
40.57, 28.11, 33.13, 20.33, 28.99, 31.28, 32.18, 33.11, 36.15, 
39.52, 37.24, 35.18, 37.5, 38.79, 40.19, 42.63, 37.34, 44.08, 
43.81, 36.88, 32.42, 38.88, 27.69, 33.44, 34.63, 37.6, 41.43, 
40.32, 36.36, 38.63, 36.33, 32.08, 40.8, 41.77, 30.32, 38.79, 
26.26, 22.26, 23.11, 37.9, 15.79, 29.88, 29.64, 39.54, 42.24, 
21.8, 32.42, 37.99, 37.21, 36.11, 51.71, 23.49, 40.02, 42.68, 
44.13, 35.01, 30.32, 47.3, 24.25, 44.32, 39.45, 26.52, 34.74, 
41.14, 37.52, 44.21, 45.34, 47.01, 16.99, 29.67, 16.31, 48.67, 
21.35, 41.62, 23.61, 48.6, 21.39, 28.38, 26.78, 25.09, 15.94, 
16.39, 28.34, 34.32, 46.46, 42.49, 19.86, 26.92, 25.58, 38.06, 
30.57, 51.33, 41.82, 17.43, 28.46, 29.97, 34.76, 27.46, 41.98, 
26.29, 26.8, 17.24, 39.7, 37.8, 51.78, 40.45, 30.52, 35, 44.15, 
21.42, 52.15, 33.27, 35.7, 25.26, 55.08, 21.87, 28.26, 42.21, 
43.25, 40.81, 32.57, 38.46, 33.39, 41.59, 35.56, 31.49, 31.42, 
36.27, 20.52, 35.03, 29.84, 32.56, 29.62, 53.26, 36.27, 33.21, 
54.44, 54.88, 36.02, 33.78, 45.53, 41.4, 31.9, 45.61, 51.93, 
55.99, 26.88, 43.45, 53.82, 38.02, 44.76, 43.92, 50.04, 41.6, 
47.76, 22.58, 17.62, 50.74, 45.2, 56.84, 48.09, 31.51, 50.76, 
17.82, 43.37, 24.66, 50.32, 19.46, 23.32, 42.51, 44.18, 40.78, 
21.15, 20.74, 22.73, 15.18, 39.2, 48.03, 39.41, 38.52, 43.21, 
25.51, 42.72, 37.73, 20.88, 18.94, 32.94, 27.61, 21.83, 34.76, 
23.52, 36.57, 28.07, 30.09, 38.58, 42.76, 43.87, 37.67, 41.2, 
39.13, 39.19, 39.52, 14.91, 38.47, 32.61, 28.45, 41.2, 44.24), 
AEA = c(28.25, 27.96, 38.15, 48.97, 31.64, 29.25, 23.3, 15.62, 
39.07, 47.96, 38.13, 21.47, 36.5, 30.81, 41.46, 33.89, 31.93, 
29.46, 44.67, 31.07, 40.27, 36.98, 45.35, 51.1, 41.07, 24.96, 
23.94, 28.9, 46.36, 29.94, 44.49, 44.48, 35.4, 49.12, 29.13, 
41.23, 48.22, 48.3, 21.72, 19.72, 23.74, 44.49, 36.43, 38.2, 
36.14, 38.49, 33.69, 30.61, 30.18, 43.78, 45.69, 47.72, 46.59, 
39.86, 24.77, 35.97, 43.05, 25.13, 40.77, 22.64, 38.11, 11.71, 
37.02, 39.92, 30.15, 33.38, 36.08, 37.06, 34.96, 15.86, 36.99, 
22.72, 29.91, 23.01, 31.17, 35.27, 39.98, 41.74, 45.05, 31.55, 
27.65, 45.23, 43.88, 46.64, 36.9, 36.87, 29.13, 31.93, 37.39, 
24.07, 38.94, 50.03, 35.78, 47.77, 16, 39.52, 25.2, 44.55, 
43.82, 25.42, 54.65, 34.93, 19.9, 29.17, 46.79, 36.55, 37.91, 
19.16, 14.23, 32.48, 24.98, 45.98, 32.17, 30.17, 40.18, 39.61, 
36.11, 20.66, 30.75, 25.05, 39.26, 37.65, 38.79, 35.25, 34.26, 
29.85, 31.36, 17.17, 18.59, 29.44, 38.56, 44.02, 18.73, 42.73, 
17.76, 36.98, 33.43, 34.97, 23.2, 50.31, 39.86, 12.49, 24.53, 
56.6, 45.33, 36.07, 18.56, 23.38, 39.13, 41.67, 35.5, 36.98, 
55.22, 42.89, 23.67, 39.66, 38.51, 48.93, 37.39, 42.21, 42.79, 
35.73, 45.62, 34.08, 43.77, 43.31, 38.04, 36.98, 31.03, 20.58, 
55.91, 34.5, 30.83, 35.85, 46.1, 43.7, 20.23, 30.74, 41.79, 
35.74, 42.58, 45.04, 48.57, 33.26, 28.62, 31.72, 23.09, 44.55, 
40, 30.03, 43.86, 22.84, 44.11, 42.82, 33.19, 31.09, 40, 
42.11, 39.21, 36.5, 49.4, 48.06, 36.55, 42.71, 40, 38.1, 
44.56, 27.05, 29.27, 40.55, 29.64, 35.7, 28.22, 17.69, 44.76, 
33.69, 37.44, 38.85, 26.6, 39.13, 55.28, 41.77, 47.28, 24.88, 
40.17, 26.31, 38.32, 47.15, 23.99, 29.04, 31.16, 27.36, 45.95, 
42.9, 32.43, 33.89, 34.34, 33.84, 47.87, 23.98, 46.92, 31.16, 
40.93, 41.33, 32.44, 51.93, 34.46, 36.2, 45.97, 32.11, 44.74, 
39.76, 47.28, 39.87, 40.62, 50.47, 18.03, 19.45, 15.67, 29.17, 
18.17, 39.54, 15.11, 31.63, 22.38, 36.62, 27.07, 38.75, 20.85, 
24.17, 16.9, 21.79, 47.99, 29.62, 19.86, 12.29, 28.67, 35.9, 
32.96, 31.3, 42.96, 11.21, 26.01, 27.08, 18.29, 16.03, 39.38, 
20.72, 42.86, 25.34, 46.5, 11.99, 47.96, 48.16, 25.68, 33.31, 
47.68, 38.28, 50.02, 28.6, 41.95, 27.53, 48.04, 34.85, 33.36, 
26.26, 51.42, 37.95, 49.2, 47.5, 23.21, 30.26, 43.56, 41.43, 
31.58, 28.61, 16.5, 42.09, 18.55, 17.79, 25.78, 24.69, 17.86, 
43.71, 34.4, 22.86, 35.76, 30.66, 27.75, 22.76, 44.72, 33.96, 
39.91, 43.56, 21.23, 40.58, 57.96, 45.92, 26.55, 39.85, 38.77, 
28.42, 27.49, 21.97, 14.93, 44.06, 44.78, 52.96, 33.52, 37.9, 
26.02, 19.51, 33.05, 11.14, 41.1, 20.67, 24.34, 43.39, 30.87, 
22.9, 30.64, 18.17, 18.15, 21.13, 26.91, 50.79, 30.62, 37.64, 
27.23, 21.92, 45.19, 29.66, 26.27, 29.15, 20.93, 23.27, 17.2, 
46.23, 18.1, 33.77, 26.81, 21.5, 35.66, 31.15, 32.89, 40.14, 
43.64, 39.79, 45.23, 36.39, 13.33, 30.48, 22.8, 17.36, 25.64, 
32.28), TL = c(1611.73, 2000.03, 1708.56, 1482.78, 1930.17, 
1517.96, 1645.54, 875.36, 363.9, 1211.11, 707.75, 126, 1896.33, 
1201.09, 1666.03, 399.99, 899.19, 1440.9, 1220.85, 441.89, 
1301.19, 411.25, 1058.35, 690.71, 468.28, 493.29, 696.64, 
720.94, 937.48, 873.6, 1161.28, 1183.29, 1187.31, 1383.79, 
1282.36, 1401.17, 1664.07, 1302.93, 933.67, 87.4, 93.95, 
1195.63, 1438.75, 1319.66, 1418.64, 1327.36, 1144.91, 948.1, 
1321.69, 762.5, 997.04, 1440.75, 1408.02, 866.92, 1246.34, 
598.59, 1063.82, 1085.85, 1207.25, 134.17, 1140.67, 985.6, 
322.6, 1465.07, 967.79, 1599.73, 952, 1299.05, 1393.75, 91.43, 
990.4, 578.34, 1172.86, 54.6, 91.27, 303.89, 572.89, 451.17, 
789.86, 486.99, 724.69, 945.37, 770.01, 781.5, 854.24, 757.08, 
800.99, 1151.25, 878.57, 993.9, 1321.97, 1026.26, 1940.87, 
1102.77, 119.1, 1022.64, 387.96, 733.32, 733.32, 1763.76, 
1513.12, 1817.78, 1135.1, 831.09, 34.03, 1369.28, 917.96, 
908.13, 683.13, 1166.54, 807.42, 1153.25, 1565.59, 150.23, 
680.17, 1928.68, 1016.73, 66.74, 1112.68, 197.12, 1074.66, 
1066.72, 1492.29, 1734.69, 1637.43, 989.48, 1599.23, 579.92, 
719.32, 587.93, 1138.26, 1221.17, 155.19, 1725.77, 588.6, 
1312.38, 313.34, 1613.8, 338.36, 1151.78, 1049.66, 581.26, 
620.8, 1100.6, 903.21, 927.57, 546.59, 592.5, 1515.52, 1529.04, 
989.13, 1136.83, 820.87, 1473.18, 501.83, 1297.74, 1046.32, 
1561.67, 1189.51, 1509.71, 1950.75, 889.54, 1626.39, 963.38, 
1104.73, 1347.17, 1233.09, 1157.94, 244.12, 844.23, 1090.23, 
1261.21, 1398.66, 1598.67, 1103.24, 1434.42, 1490.93, 1162.7, 
1148.45, 1617.38, 1756.51, 1556.14, 1596.56, 389.17, 962.41, 
389.78, 331.44, 1434.05, 1132.93, 1162.65, 739.07, 839.96, 
1356.59, 1242.56, 1274.23, 1185.76, 1553.95, 762.44, 704.39, 
864.76, 751.27, 934.28, 676.79, 1327.19, 1216.19, 1323.44, 
1263.23, 1029, 1365.65, 1311.42, 754.7, 1032.19, 785.28, 
1059.54, 949.51, 1104.21, 1472.86, 1380.74, 488.81, 586.57, 
812.65, 43.01, 971.71, 1273, 1386.87, 471.91, 1279.95, 1419.04, 
746.12, 603.88, 599.53, 1193.19, 772.09, 656.75, 1269.64, 
1592.46, 224.31, 1565.19, 314.17, 732.08, 797.02, 650.48, 
979.58, 981.88, 1021.67, 1033.49, 615.97, 879.24, 1202.83, 
891.77, 752.86, 1100.06, 1435.95, 1490.92, 1700.68, 988.49, 
306.85, 1598.08, 2026.11, 1797.46, 1713.56, 1931.49, 1454.85, 
1738.81, 606.43, 444.09, 205.4, 169.68, 257.38, 231.88, 400.34, 
815.09, 307, 647.04, 35.05, 367.68, 311.54, 751.33, 1009.03, 
935.37, 157.38, 308.69, 709.07, 388.39, 449.79, 376.5, 947.29, 
118.91, 1197.86, 87.95, 332.69, 166.82, 354.31, 1606.2, 291.69, 
1249.39, 242.86, 1224.76, 124.8, 1411.4, 931.46, 1235.16, 
281.03, 243.04, 122.92, 1477.23, 1265.99, 611.88, 842.57, 
1560.03, 750.99, 441.94, 959.78, 958.17, 839.82, 1669.83, 
574.74, 1224.5, 2036.75, 611.1, 1038.6, 1270.32, 1408.93, 
819.38, 1488.12, 1609.87, 2077.33, 542.6, 1224.49, 897.21, 
526.17, 1255.22, 1024.2, 1094.07, 883.58, 1474.83, 254.22, 
685.91, 773.99, 369.43, 1067.1, 836.8, 161.94, 195.51, 71.42, 
263.71, 67.52, 199.61, 1022.58, 633.86, 383.58, 1067.64, 
489.93, 537.01, 685.4, 397.12, 656.74, 81.97, 661.04, 622.34, 
588.71, 840.62, 486.15, 293.62, 1457.94, 365.49, 1087.82, 
914.33, 1186.08, 621.2, 1609.02, 857.75, 821.89, 704.72, 
422.94, 1526.63, 1017.96, 1205.47, 776.56, 1489.03, 2100.99, 
842.79, 1763.54, 1767.1, 1970.65, 126.37, 1428.01, 2166.15, 
1766.8, 1556.1, 854.55, 807.59, 455.12, 542.3, 146.07, 355.4
), AL = c(322.35, 400.01, 341.71, 247.13, 386.03, 303.59, 
329.11, 291.79, 90.97, 242.22, 176.94, 25.2, 379.27, 300.27, 
333.21, 66.67, 149.87, 288.18, 244.17, 110.47, 260.24, 137.08, 
264.59, 138.14, 156.09, 164.43, 174.16, 180.24, 187.5, 218.4, 
232.26, 236.66, 237.46, 276.76, 320.59, 280.23, 332.81, 260.59, 
186.73, 21.85, 23.49, 239.13, 287.75, 329.91, 354.66, 331.84, 
228.98, 189.62, 440.56, 254.17, 249.26, 288.15, 352.01, 288.97, 
311.58, 149.65, 212.76, 361.95, 241.45, 33.54, 285.17, 328.53, 
107.53, 366.27, 193.56, 399.93, 190.4, 259.81, 278.75, 30.48, 
198.08, 144.58, 293.21, 18.2, 30.42, 101.3, 143.22, 150.39, 
157.97, 162.33, 181.17, 189.07, 192.5, 195.37, 213.56, 252.36, 
267, 287.81, 292.86, 331.3, 440.66, 256.56, 388.17, 220.55, 
29.78, 204.53, 129.32, 146.66, 146.66, 352.75, 302.62, 363.56, 
227.02, 166.22, 17.02, 342.32, 183.59, 302.71, 136.63, 291.63, 
269.14, 288.31, 313.12, 37.56, 226.72, 321.45, 254.18, 22.25, 
222.54, 65.71, 268.67, 266.68, 298.46, 346.94, 327.49, 197.9, 
319.85, 115.98, 239.77, 146.98, 284.57, 244.23, 51.73, 345.15, 
117.72, 262.48, 78.33, 322.76, 84.59, 230.36, 209.93, 193.75, 
124.16, 220.12, 180.64, 185.51, 109.32, 118.5, 303.1, 305.81, 
197.83, 284.21, 410.44, 294.64, 100.37, 259.55, 209.26, 312.33, 
237.9, 301.94, 390.15, 222.38, 325.28, 192.68, 220.95, 269.43, 
246.62, 231.59, 48.82, 422.12, 218.05, 420.4, 349.66, 399.67, 
220.65, 286.88, 372.73, 232.54, 229.69, 323.48, 351.3, 311.23, 
319.31, 97.29, 320.8, 77.96, 82.86, 286.81, 226.59, 387.55, 
184.77, 279.99, 271.32, 248.51, 318.56, 296.44, 310.79, 152.49, 
234.8, 172.95, 150.25, 186.86, 169.2, 265.44, 243.24, 264.69, 
315.81, 205.8, 341.41, 327.86, 188.68, 258.05, 261.76, 353.18, 
237.38, 220.84, 368.21, 276.15, 162.94, 146.64, 203.16, 14.34, 
194.34, 254.6, 346.72, 157.3, 213.33, 283.81, 149.22, 201.29, 
199.84, 238.64, 154.42, 164.19, 253.93, 318.49, 56.08, 391.3, 
104.72, 146.42, 159.4, 162.62, 195.92, 196.38, 204.33, 206.7, 
153.99, 219.81, 240.57, 222.94, 188.22, 275.02, 287.19, 298.18, 
340.14, 197.7, 61.37, 319.62, 337.69, 299.58, 285.59, 321.92, 
242.48, 347.76, 101.07, 148.03, 68.47, 84.84, 64.34, 77.29, 
133.45, 271.7, 102.33, 129.41, 17.53, 183.84, 103.85, 250.44, 
252.26, 187.07, 78.69, 102.9, 354.53, 97.1, 149.93, 188.25, 
189.46, 59.45, 239.57, 43.97, 110.9, 83.41, 118.1, 321.24, 
97.23, 249.88, 60.71, 306.19, 41.6, 352.85, 186.29, 308.79, 
93.68, 81.01, 61.46, 295.45, 253.2, 122.38, 280.86, 312.01, 
375.5, 147.31, 239.95, 191.63, 209.96, 333.97, 114.95, 244.9, 
407.35, 203.7, 173.1, 254.06, 234.82, 204.85, 297.62, 321.97, 
415.47, 135.65, 244.9, 224.3, 175.39, 251.04, 204.84, 273.52, 
176.72, 294.97, 127.11, 171.48, 154.8, 123.14, 213.42, 167.36, 
53.98, 48.88, 35.71, 131.85, 33.76, 49.9, 340.86, 211.29, 
191.79, 177.94, 163.31, 268.5, 137.08, 132.37, 218.91, 27.32, 
132.21, 155.59, 98.12, 140.1, 97.23, 48.94, 291.59, 121.83, 
217.56, 182.87, 197.68, 124.24, 321.8, 171.55, 164.38, 176.18, 
140.98, 254.44, 339.32, 241.09, 129.43, 297.81, 420.2, 280.93, 
352.71, 353.42, 394.13, 25.27, 285.6, 361.03, 353.36, 311.22, 
170.91, 161.52, 113.78, 135.58, 73.03, 177.7), RC = c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L), CH = c(99796.6, 150717.35, 169751.56, 
138012.75, 145077.46, 112201.58, 114565.78, 29620.4, 8114.84, 
104093.06, 41066.73, 382.14, 149702.87, 92373.87, 158251.21, 
6220.25, 34758.22, 112415.55, 82849.16, 9090.06, 51765.37, 
16842.27, 88999.49, 44639.16, 17088.07, 16880.06, 36641.48, 
33244.5, 60371.65, 43912.9, 77793.71, 86013.44, 81057.21, 
116609.76, 111212.8, 83104.24, 136636.59, 112152.81, 43416.08, 
283.33, 374.67, 90389.3, 114615.27, 127323.54, 122751.22, 
105850.82, 91786.61, 23112.34, 133294.75, 27773.3, 49075.11, 
93961.22, 144848.22, 77854.05, 65839.32, 24644.95, 61791.45, 
74955.5, 92759.51, 964.97, 87895.4, 21552.75, 7974, 123189.55, 
56441.2, 145209.81, 47723.32, 79965.64, 102406.65, 337.25, 
66525.5, 9440, 79655.87, 176.68, 730.37, 5127.66, 20335.05, 
16666.69, 38090.42, 20058.33, 11775.04, 50170.86, 36106.37, 
61313.49, 43396.46, 47042.07, 49551.7, 91789.19, 48686.24, 
64761.22, 156197.85, 55463.72, 153143.15, 64908.28, 506.14, 
56835.13, 6120.06, 21167.83, 21211.43, 87971.16, 90657.94, 
171831.58, 65430.27, 17854.84, 143.88, 91421.95, 34874.29, 
38881.59, 3485.86, 99421.46, 36734.34, 92497.02, 104054.94, 
940.84, 30819.4, 140446.17, 73149.38, 269.12, 68028.56, 2113.16, 
74108.99, 61726.85, 103843.73, 115498.2, 152778.67, 40062.47, 
137124.42, 13089.39, 35384.17, 13814.31, 101758.52, 72365.21, 
1278.51, 133907.82, 21664.34, 89772.79, 5596.74, 127352.18, 
8147.31, 58849.79, 39310.16, 16462, 16314.24, 67631.15, 46364.97, 
64883.46, 9567.38, 10933.67, 107106.85, 85896.08, 36002.96, 
99832.8, 96843.38, 168697.71, 11437, 89556.61, 64397.67, 
175431.79, 99090.85, 137239, 177246.87, 16387.22, 129327.61, 
49607.1, 84182.02, 103011.14, 76487.65, 68888.93, 2282.16, 
40631.51, 84576.92, 136079.95, 102144.36, 170229.88, 80668.54, 
122418.68, 36610.94, 54793.71, 71040.25, 119430.26, 124054.15, 
158980.28, 115531.49, 7677, 52408.88, 5199.15, 1576.3, 117319.45, 
65816.75, 107784.21, 21943.18, 44438.61, 79339.9, 94229.06, 
78243.95, 87762.86, 102039.27, 27904.08, 33803.89, 30992.8, 
22984.68, 52859.31, 32240, 96533.18, 110382.23, 90531.02, 
156301.06, 74191.42, 101508.11, 126192.09, 25026.39, 52022.31, 
54502.27, 54906.39, 46723.31, 64956.56, 164183.81, 106144.3, 
15816.24, 25480.55, 40012.96, 187.89, 28777.54, 60948.7, 
111351.64, 18846.81, 44388.99, 98196.75, 13827.13, 23302.71, 
23032.36, 78314.21, 43668.82, 21560.18, 81402.92, 110253.4, 
2468, 161127.06, 6728.38, 24954.59, 29634.28, 19529.65, 62234.38, 
77694.07, 39340.43, 67121.62, 17881.17, 53538.79, 92126.96, 
27319.28, 37817.88, 83791.37, 123852.55, 119991.03, 155539.82, 
59573.35, 2017.04, 65310.24, 67034.04, 85421.53, 45188.09, 
142873.37, 42077.58, 118492.3, 8899.7, 12988.53, 2414.63, 
748.24, 1635.91, 1649.83, 12088.91, 21986.38, 5871.28, 17082.53, 
89.46, 5935.65, 4201.11, 48657.16, 60375.11, 19427.75, 3066.9, 
3634.67, 56680.85, 8585.62, 10017.71, 8010.08, 38352.11, 
861.56, 63114, 778.52, 6436.22, 1594.19, 11462.7, 147823.51, 
3663.95, 68565.01, 3541.49, 111886, 1550, 102544.23, 46836.23, 
57453.23, 7184.43, 3564.13, 827.86, 81637.61, 63919.09, 29682.26, 
69984.84, 139094.03, 66276.96, 10650.41, 36945, 35774.31, 
44166.05, 73627.28, 6224.87, 41446.36, 91344.8, 30789.52, 
45791.66, 66309.25, 21550.8, 37335.77, 76399.5, 59260.5, 
139885.86, 12678.87, 32494.66, 43462.29, 28585.93, 58488.41, 
38932.21, 72211.27, 37080.1, 120925.26, 8037.65, 39036.09, 
12348, 11398.33, 76742.36, 45091.44, 2286.63, 1037.5, 377.59, 
5550.86, 568, 2742.84, 40443.88, 31255.25, 15853.41, 12635.68, 
24472.5, 31640.11, 25472.72, 8286.29, 44970.06, 514.17, 29406, 
18771.87, 11593.36, 38816.45, 3866.89, 1358.91, 67884.5, 
15016.07, 39352.47, 40707.85, 67124.98, 16286.1, 118673.4, 
43579.93, 31756.41, 32294.47, 11045, 56989.65, 27077.35, 
63791.55, 7803.23, 83200.54, 121846.69, 50495.22, 131891.93, 
129093.86, 159164.54, 753.21, 99728.86, 175305.54, 151381.78, 
114235.61, 8781.88, 31090, 11269.42, 11908.07, 554.04, 4928.65
), MW = c(427L, 456L, 331L, 308L, 479L, 411L, 330L, 158L, 
60L, 360L, 352L, 17L, 432L, 488L, 550L, 76L, 179L, 541L, 
443L, 66L, 219L, 109L, 318L, 191L, 220L, 111L, 258L, 173L, 
355L, 250L, 318L, 424L, 350L, 420L, 422L, 421L, 573L, 521L, 
199L, 16L, 23L, 399L, 347L, 521L, 549L, 336L, 231L, 104L, 
491L, 131L, 161L, 357L, 479L, 261L, 305L, 152L, 308L, 520L, 
437L, 26L, 450L, 99L, 64L, 556L, 176L, 526L, 311L, 379L, 
382L, 14L, 354L, 70L, 442L, 13L, 32L, 57L, 193L, 117L, 308L, 
157L, 60L, 222L, 195L, 328L, 237L, 282L, 241L, 217L, 325L, 
265L, 506L, 260L, 475L, 382L, 22L, 222L, 45L, 239L, 239L, 
252L, 395L, 518L, 319L, 105L, 15L, 396L, 158L, 128L, 20L, 
293L, 125L, 365L, 259L, 14L, 112L, 515L, 274L, 17L, 332L, 
27L, 139L, 297L, 474L, 298L, 567L, 202L, 468L, 87L, 275L, 
132L, 441L, 333L, 23L, 452L, 221L, 431L, 63L, 434L, 80L, 
324L, 145L, 189L, 80L, 438L, 234L, 351L, 59L, 83L, 474L, 
263L, 224L, 510L, 479L, 555L, 74L, 327L, 350L, 563L, 519L, 
507L, 534L, 83L, 546L, 289L, 301L, 506L, 375L, 388L, 36L, 
155L, 418L, 540L, 353L, 522L, 368L, 523L, 96L, 255L, 277L, 
357L, 350L, 487L, 347L, 86L, 269L, 41L, 24L, 311L, 398L, 
422L, 154L, 221L, 278L, 365L, 304L, 257L, 324L, 195L, 290L, 
191L, 176L, 313L, 260L, 471L, 486L, 415L, 579L, 439L, 361L, 
433L, 184L, 285L, 273L, 228L, 288L, 386L, 536L, 500L, 53L, 
122L, 259L, 10L, 125L, 246L, 419L, 188L, 217L, 457L, 76L, 
257L, 257L, 327L, 155L, 120L, 339L, 480L, 34L, 552L, 74L, 
124L, 269L, 216L, 301L, 374L, 131L, 243L, 169L, 240L, 390L, 
137L, 229L, 421L, 334L, 482L, 496L, 236L, 24L, 225L, 211L, 
406L, 194L, 504L, 243L, 541L, 88L, 156L, 61L, 8L, 25L, 23L, 
149L, 62L, 56L, 103L, 10L, 48L, 35L, 290L, 283L, 164L, 92L, 
16L, 306L, 118L, 84L, 70L, 214L, 24L, 356L, 28L, 46L, 8L, 
150L, 516L, 38L, 405L, 80L, 339L, 50L, 338L, 258L, 326L, 
124L, 44L, 12L, 212L, 323L, 239L, 447L, 529L, 425L, 84L, 
228L, 240L, 304L, 332L, 64L, 241L, 316L, 226L, 163L, 256L, 
87L, 153L, 409L, 315L, 534L, 168L, 205L, 294L, 190L, 345L, 
244L, 342L, 156L, 491L, 175L, 230L, 100L, 79L, 385L, 351L, 
57L, 23L, 14L, 38L, 40L, 67L, 180L, 290L, 140L, 42L, 267L, 
267L, 171L, 66L, 348L, 40L, 303L, 166L, 46L, 292L, 45L, 19L, 
358L, 162L, 358L, 311L, 408L, 114L, 439L, 191L, 192L, 181L, 
168L, 348L, 119L, 284L, 51L, 325L, 340L, 238L, 455L, 478L, 
557L, 25L, 411L, 608L, 458L, 465L, 43L, 293L, 128L, 71L, 
15L, 33L), MD = c(594L, 607L, 703L, 603L, 565L, 512L, 627L, 
501L, 382L, 686L, 389L, 126L, 523L, 461L, 575L, 184L, 299L, 
417L, 337L, 265L, 389L, 246L, 575L, 354L, 284L, 282L, 305L, 
468L, 330L, 377L, 476L, 589L, 497L, 529L, 520L, 470L, 546L, 
601L, 607L, 129L, 111L, 426L, 620L, 510L, 470L, 491L, 527L, 
333L, 541L, 359L, 485L, 435L, 561L, 538L, 341L, 362L, 437L, 
521L, 614L, 121L, 433L, 478L, 256L, 459L, 450L, 497L, 290L, 
395L, 495L, 58L, 376L, 240L, 367L, 100L, 120L, 308L, 301L, 
280L, 235L, 264L, 463L, 540L, 369L, 352L, 340L, 343L, 424L, 
557L, 307L, 471L, 568L, 493L, 725L, 498L, 113L, 441L, 252L, 
251L, 252L, 615L, 388L, 614L, 387L, 317L, 65L, 529L, 555L, 
702L, 305L, 634L, 567L, 525L, 641L, 135L, 495L, 497L, 480L, 
51L, 415L, 178L, 602L, 365L, 500L, 685L, 663L, 562L, 587L, 
357L, 301L, 250L, 450L, 415L, 137L, 408L, 204L, 368L, 164L, 
502L, 200L, 288L, 314L, 212L, 482L, 385L, 512L, 528L, 342L, 
335L, 435L, 556L, 351L, 402L, 377L, 605L, 231L, 495L, 381L, 
672L, 575L, 669L, 694L, 378L, 485L, 325L, 508L, 439L, 393L, 
370L, 173L, 480L, 428L, 522L, 690L, 734L, 583L, 465L, 653L, 
424L, 369L, 576L, 598L, 610L, 576L, 169L, 401L, 232L, 152L, 
710L, 383L, 501L, 233L, 380L, 416L, 645L, 621L, 561L, 561L, 
320L, 256L, 376L, 257L, 364L, 259L, 381L, 529L, 497L, 728L, 
517L, 630L, 562L, 316L, 403L, 415L, 496L, 299L, 343L, 591L, 
394L, 373L, 331L, 302L, 176L, 583L, 416L, 534L, 255L, 403L, 
462L, 366L, 209L, 210L, 363L, 394L, 266L, 473L, 448L, 183L, 
590L, 207L, 449L, 207L, 200L, 441L, 419L, 440L, 514L, 252L, 
577L, 452L, 333L, 309L, 488L, 540L, 452L, 665L, 479L, 278L, 
616L, 618L, 348L, 433L, 509L, 340L, 478L, 215L, 271L, 319L, 
196L, 164L, 251L, 303L, 585L, 229L, 294L, 118L, 248L, 192L, 
293L, 486L, 413L, 283L, 334L, 400L, 145L, 171L, 243L, 360L, 
99L, 469L, 196L, 365L, 194L, 198L, 455L, 235L, 380L, 120L, 
504L, 110L, 475L, 248L, 361L, 145L, 150L, 145L, 581L, 540L, 
301L, 361L, 518L, 398L, 254L, 326L, 330L, 286L, 610L, 237L, 
418L, 617L, 274L, 375L, 337L, 378L, 366L, 447L, 545L, 507L, 
212L, 346L, 363L, 280L, 367L, 266L, 323L, 393L, 460L, 246L, 
338L, 311L, 227L, 325L, 262L, 93L, 104L, 98L, 185L, 64L, 
118L, 503L, 359L, 427L, 398L, 251L, 342L, 275L, 235L, 276L, 
53L, 342L, 314L, 500L, 474L, 214L, 200L, 360L, 216L, 272L, 
297L, 323L, 277L, 375L, 339L, 290L, 316L, 260L, 458L, 580L, 
541L, 285L, 481L, 642L, 417L, 567L, 521L, 535L, 93L, 449L, 
515L, 501L, 443L, 350L, 244L, 357L, 330L, 113L, 196L), `W/D` = c(0.72, 
0.75, 0.47, 0.51, 0.85, 0.8, 0.53, 0.32, 0.16, 0.52, 0.9, 
0.13, 0.83, 1.06, 0.96, 0.41, 0.6, 1.3, 1.31, 0.25, 0.56, 
0.44, 0.55, 0.54, 0.77, 0.39, 0.85, 0.37, 1.08, 0.66, 0.67, 
0.72, 0.7, 0.79, 0.81, 0.9, 1.05, 0.87, 0.33, 0.12, 0.21, 
0.94, 0.56, 1.02, 1.17, 0.68, 0.44, 0.31, 0.91, 0.36, 0.33, 
0.82, 0.85, 0.49, 0.89, 0.42, 0.7, 1, 0.71, 0.21, 1.04, 0.21, 
0.25, 1.21, 0.39, 1.06, 1.07, 0.96, 0.77, 0.24, 0.94, 0.29, 
1.2, 0.13, 0.27, 0.19, 0.64, 0.42, 1.31, 0.59, 0.13, 0.41, 
0.53, 0.93, 0.7, 0.82, 0.57, 0.39, 1.06, 0.56, 0.89, 0.53, 
0.66, 0.77, 0.19, 0.5, 0.18, 0.95, 0.95, 0.41, 1.02, 0.84, 
0.82, 0.33, 0.23, 0.75, 0.28, 0.18, 0.07, 0.46, 0.22, 0.7, 
0.4, 0.1, 0.23, 1.04, 0.57, 0.33, 0.8, 0.15, 0.23, 0.81, 
0.95, 0.44, 0.86, 0.36, 0.8, 0.24, 0.91, 0.53, 0.98, 0.8, 
0.17, 1.11, 1.08, 1.17, 0.38, 0.86, 0.4, 1.12, 0.46, 0.89, 
0.17, 1.14, 0.46, 0.66, 0.17, 0.25, 1.09, 0.47, 0.64, 1.27, 
1.27, 0.92, 0.32, 0.66, 0.92, 0.84, 0.9, 0.76, 0.77, 0.22, 
1.13, 0.89, 0.59, 1.15, 0.95, 1.05, 0.21, 0.32, 0.98, 1.03, 
0.51, 0.71, 0.63, 1.12, 0.15, 0.6, 0.75, 0.62, 0.59, 0.8, 
0.6, 0.51, 0.67, 0.18, 0.16, 0.44, 1.04, 0.84, 0.66, 0.58, 
0.67, 0.57, 0.49, 0.46, 0.58, 0.61, 1.13, 0.51, 0.68, 0.86, 
1, 1.24, 0.92, 0.84, 0.8, 0.85, 0.57, 0.77, 0.58, 0.71, 0.66, 
0.46, 0.96, 1.13, 0.91, 1.27, 0.14, 0.37, 0.86, 0.06, 0.21, 
0.59, 0.78, 0.74, 0.54, 0.99, 0.21, 1.23, 1.22, 0.9, 0.39, 
0.45, 0.72, 1.07, 0.19, 0.94, 0.36, 0.28, 1.3, 1.08, 0.68, 
0.89, 0.3, 0.47, 0.67, 0.42, 0.86, 0.41, 0.74, 0.86, 0.62, 
1.07, 0.75, 0.49, 0.09, 0.37, 0.34, 1.17, 0.45, 0.99, 0.71, 
1.13, 0.41, 0.58, 0.19, 0.04, 0.15, 0.09, 0.49, 0.11, 0.24, 
0.35, 0.08, 0.19, 0.18, 0.99, 0.58, 0.4, 0.33, 0.05, 0.76, 
0.81, 0.49, 0.29, 0.59, 0.24, 0.76, 0.14, 0.13, 0.04, 0.76, 
1.13, 0.16, 1.07, 0.67, 0.67, 0.45, 0.71, 1.04, 0.9, 0.86, 
0.29, 0.08, 0.36, 0.6, 0.79, 1.24, 1.02, 1.07, 0.33, 0.7, 
0.73, 1.06, 0.54, 0.27, 0.58, 0.51, 0.82, 0.43, 0.76, 0.23, 
0.42, 0.91, 0.58, 1.05, 0.79, 0.59, 0.81, 0.68, 0.94, 0.92, 
1.06, 0.4, 1.07, 0.71, 0.68, 0.32, 0.35, 1.18, 1.34, 0.61, 
0.22, 0.14, 0.21, 0.62, 0.57, 0.36, 0.81, 0.33, 0.11, 1.06, 
0.78, 0.62, 0.28, 1.26, 0.75, 0.89, 0.53, 0.09, 0.62, 0.21, 
0.1, 0.99, 0.75, 1.32, 1.05, 1.26, 0.41, 1.17, 0.56, 0.66, 
0.57, 0.65, 0.76, 0.21, 0.52, 0.18, 0.68, 0.53, 0.57, 0.8, 
0.92, 1.04, 0.27, 0.92, 1.18, 0.91, 1.05, 0.12, 1.2, 0.36, 
0.22, 0.13, 0.17)), .Names = c("ATA", "AEA", "TL", "AL", 
"RC", "CH", "MW", "MD", "W/D"), row.names = c(NA, -396L), class = 
c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried to do this with ggcorr function and I ended up with a graph, which I am very happy of. But I don't understand why it look to have "avoided" to do the correlation between W/D and other variables.

This is the function that I run:

```
ggcorr(df,label = TRUE,name = "Spearman correlation coeff. (ρ)", 
label_size = 3, hjust = 0.75, size = 5, color = "grey40", low = "#3399FF", 
mid = "#FFFF66", high = "#CC0033", method = c("pairwise", "spearman"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 11))
```

And I got this warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 8 rows containing missing values (geom_tile). 
2: Removed 8 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
```

It seems to remove the correlations between W/D and all the other varaiables.I think that the problem is in the last column W/D.

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPPT7.png)

Comment: Can you have a look at this: [making a reproducible r example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and provide your sample dataframe using the `dput()` function. Then I can try to reproduce it. Right now it is difficult the way you have provided the sample data. Appreciate it :)

Comment: Hello Jason, thanks for your suggestion! I just edited my post, hope that it is clear right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for updating. Next time, I recommend you also include the libraries you loaded. Anyways, here is the full reproducible solution which I ran successfully on my machine with no errors. Have a look at the package versions I have installed which is from `sessionInfo()`. Perhaps try doing `install.packages()` for both the packages loaded and see if you still get the same error after updating to the latest versions. My first guess was that you were missing values, but as you can see `colSums(is.na(df))` I checked to see if there were any missing values in any of the columns, but there were none.

This is how I got this fully reproducible example below (I just deleted the `df` part because it was too long and you already have it in the question):

`library(reprex); reprex(venue='so', si=TRUE)`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
#> Warning: package 'GGally' was built under R version 3.4.1

ggcorr(df,label = TRUE,name = "Spearman correlation coeff. (ρ)", 
       label_size = 3, hjust = 0.75, size = 5, color = "grey40", low = "#3399FF", 
       mid = "#FFFF66", high = "#CC0033", method = c("pairwise", "spearman"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 11))
```

[image]

```r
colSums(is.na(df))
#> ATA AEA  TL  AL  RC  CH  MW  MD W/D 
#>   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0


devtools::session_info()
#> Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(Sys.time()): unknown timezone 'default/
#> America/Vancouver'
#> Session info -------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
#>  system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       <NA>                        
#>  date     2017-09-26
#> Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package      * version date       source         
#>  backports      1.1.0   2017-05-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  base         * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local          
#>  colorspace     1.3-2   2016-12-14 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  compiler       3.4.0   2017-04-21 local          
#>  datasets     * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local          
#>  devtools       1.13.3  2017-08-02 CRAN (R 3.4.1) 
#>  digest         0.6.12  2017-01-27 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  evaluate       0.10.1  2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.1) 
#>  GGally       * 1.3.2   2017-08-02 CRAN (R 3.4.1) 
#>  ggplot2      * 2.2.1   2016-12-30 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  graphics     * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local          
#>  grDevices    * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local          
#>  grid           3.4.0   2017-04-21 local          
#>  gtable         0.2.0   2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  htmltools      0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  knitr          1.17    2017-08-10 CRAN (R 3.4.1) 
#>  labeling       0.3     2014-08-23 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  lazyeval       0.2.0   2016-06-12 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  magrittr       1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  memoise        1.1.0   2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  methods      * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local          
#>  munsell        0.4.3   2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  plyr           1.8.4   2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  RColorBrewer   1.1-2   2014-12-07 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  Rcpp           0.12.12 2017-07-15 cran (@0.12.12)
#>  reshape        0.8.7   2017-08-06 CRAN (R 3.4.1) 
#>  rlang          0.1.2   2017-08-09 CRAN (R 3.4.1) 
#>  rmarkdown      1.6     2017-06-15 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  rprojroot      1.2     2017-01-16 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  scales         0.5.0   2017-08-24 CRAN (R 3.4.1) 
#>  stats        * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local          
#>  stringi        1.1.5   2017-04-07 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  stringr        1.2.0   2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.0) 
#>  tibble         1.3.4   2017-08-22 CRAN (R 3.4.1) 
#>  tools          3.4.0   2017-04-21 local          
#>  utils        * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local          
#>  withr          2.0.0   2017-07-28 CRAN (R 3.4.1) 
#>  yaml           2.1.14  2016-11-12 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason! That is what I was looking for!